# How to use Ng2-translate into *NgFor

Tags: angular, ngfor, ng2-translate

i need to translate the Data that i get in NgFor but i couldn't find any solution for it.

can any 1 find solution for this

```
<dl class="row">
    <dd class="col-sm-3" (click)="onSelect(brand)" *ngFor="let brand of searchData">
        <div style="text-align:center">{{brand.name}}</div>
        <br> 
    </dd>
</dl>
```

how can i use | translate @pipe inside this NgFor

Comment: Maybe <div style="text-align:center">{{brand.text | translate}}</div>

Comment: Can you please add some tries that you did?

Comment: GOT THE SOLUTION THIS IS WORKING FINE     <dl>
                         
                                                                                                             
  <dd> <div class="col-md-3" (click)="onSelect(brand)" *ngFor="let brand of searchData">
   <img src='assets/{{brand.name}}.jpg' height="50px" width="100px"/> <br>{{'HOME.'+brand.name | translate}}
      <br></div> </dd> </dl>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GOT THE SOLUTION THIS IS WORKING FINE

```
    <dl> <dd> 
    <div class="col-md-3" (click)="onSelect(brand)" *ngFor="let brand of searchData">
 <br>{{'HOME.'+brand.name | translate}}
     <br></div> 
    </dd> </dl>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are driving it from a ngFor then do it in the following way.

```
*ngFor="let brand of searchData" 
  
{{ ''+brand.name+'' | translate }}
```

this will help in generating the string from the object variable brand.name